# AWS service discovery for ECS through cloud formation stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, wso2, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs, service-discovery

I have configured service discovery in aws ECS service for my WSO2 gateway set up. I am able to do everything successfully manually but now I need to create cloud stack for same. When I checked aws cloud formation documentation there is AWS::ECS::Service and AWS::ServiceDiscovery::Service separately but I don't have clue how to link AWS::ECS::Service with route 53 DNS created through AWS::ServiceDiscovery::Service. Can someone help me as I am not able to know how to refer service discovery from ECS services in cloud stack.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Found below solution in cloudstack.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about cloud formation. But in terraform, You have to seprately mention a resource like below.

```
resource "aws_vpc" "example" {
  cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/16"
}

resource "aws_service_discovery_private_dns_namespace" "example" {
  name = "example.terraform.local"
  description = "example"
  vpc = "${aws_vpc.example.id}"
}

resource "aws_service_discovery_service" "example" {
  name = "example"
  dns_config {
    namespace_id = "${aws_service_discovery_private_dns_namespace.example.id}"
    dns_records {
      ttl = 10
      type = "A"
    }
    routing_policy = "MULTIVALUE"
  }

  health_check_custom_config {
    failure_threshold = 1
  }
}
```

Ref: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/service_discovery_service.html

Comment: Thanks yes its same in cloud stack as well. Code snippet is attached here.